# Website Button does not work in mobile Layout

Tags: java, html, wordpress, visual-composer, wpbakery

I have a really weird error that I'm trying to resolve. On a website I built with the visual composer, one of the buttons that leads to an internal anchor (#whatwedosmall) on the same site just wont work on the mobile layout.

This is the site: https://b8j3ssh.myraidbox.de/

I created 3 layouts (large, medium, small) and each section has a certain ID (for example the What we do section in large is named: #whatwedolarge and so on. Within the site there are buttons that lead to these sections and it works great!

However, the very first button on mobile (breakpoint smaller than 600px) just wont work at all. I tried everything but I cannot get it to work...

Can you help me?

Comment: plesae remove this style display:block; from **rs-module** class in mobile view.
Really work.

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect the page at a breakpoint < 600px you can see that your button (actually an ) is being covered by the rev_slider_1_1 so the actual  can never be hovered or clicked.

[image]

If you delete that slider from the DOM in DevTools or set the height manually, then the hovering and click work. As you can see in the screenshot below, manually setting the Slider height to 850px allows me to hover and click

[image]

You need to determine how the height of that slider is being determined and fix that in your code.

Comment: Thanks - thats a huge step forward... However, isnt it possible to somehow determine that the video is in the background or that nothing "overflows" the buttons availability?

Comment: Might be possible by setting the z-index css property. Can't advise how to do that without insight into the code

Comment: You are the best! I found an option in the composer, added the value 10 to the button and it works!!!

Comment: Glad I could help